# Not able to Insert TopicAssignment Records for Community

Tags: community

I have a Community where I need to map discussions with topics created.

I have an .csv mapping of topics to feed-Items created which I need to insert.  While inserting data into Topic Assignment Object via Work-Bench (Topic Assignment is not available in Data Loader).

I am getting the following error: **UNKNOWN ERROR: Too many object types to load: 314**

How should I map Topic with FeedItems which are shown as discussions in a Napili Theme Based Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to figure out a workaround for this. Topic Assignments Object is referred as "Records" in Data Loader. We can use Data Loader to upload Topic Assignments.

This error had something to do with Number of Objects which my Sandbox Org had.

Thank You
Gautam

Comment: @Guatam - I realise this was a long time ago, but I'm not sure I understand your answer and was wondering if you were able to provide more information here? I'm facing the same difficulty and cannot upload TopicAssignment records into a sandbox using either Dataloader or Work-bench.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems trying to insert records to the TopicAssignment Object in salesforce community using both solutions described above: Data Loader and Workbench.

I solve the issues using a very simple csv with only 3 columns:
EntityId -  The FeedItem/FeedComment/Record that you want to affect the topic with
NetworkId - If you are affecting a record visible in a Community 
TopicId - as the name says, you can get it from the Topic Object, and I recommend to filter by NetworId from your community.

I inserted more than 10k rows in my file, and if you don't exceed the limits of topics assignments you won't have any error.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that my issue was with the data in my upload - I had been using 15 character Ids in a data mapping exercise between environments. Excel can't tell the difference between Ids where the only differences are between upper and lower case letters, so some dupe Ids had crept in.

The error wasn't very clear that this was the issues, but moving to 18 character ids and re-mapping to ensure the ids were properly mapped resolved the issue.